# Identify field not in dataframe using Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following initial dataframe:

| ID | City | State |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LA | CA |

Scenario: I have created a fixed structure for the columns associated to the initial dataframe above. I have ingested a new dataset which comes in with an additional column.

I would like to compare the initial dataframe structure with the new dataset ingested. The new ingested dataset structure is as follows:

| ID | City | State | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | LA | CA |  |

Outcome: I would like to identify the column(s) which are not part of the initial dataframe. As a result, my output should be = **Country**.

I am using the following code to identify the fields associated to my dataframe:

```
df.schema.names
```

I have tried to compare the above code with the structure for the initial dataframe, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mobile phone typing is inconvenient, direct code.

```
init_cols = df.columns
new_cols = new_df.columns
result = ','.join([c for c in new_cols if c not in init_cols])
```